# Android status bar symbols

Tags: 7.0-nougat

Why has Android not made available the meaning of all the relevant status bar symbols?  Why can I not find this complete list?  I try to find out and post it, now Android is stopping me from doing this because I cannot find a ""TAG"" ???  What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly because status bar icons vary from OEM to OEM. Each one has a slightly modified icon set to go with their overall skin/UI. And then icons will depend a lot on the features incorporated within a device. So, developing a full list of icon sets seems like a tough task. Because you'll eventually miss at least something used on a phone.
Other than that, 3rd party apps also show their icons up the status bar. And it's impossible to keep a track of each and every app.